# Creating a sqlGeography LINESTRING using .NET

Tags: sql-server, gis, geospatial, sqlgeography

I am building an application that parses a variety of external map file formats (i.e. ShapeFiles, MapPoint, KML, etc.) and stores the shapes in a centralized database that will be used for a central mapping / reporting base. I have a routine that now has a line represented by an abstract array of points, and I'm attempting to turn that into a sqlGeography object that will be store in my database (SQL2012 Express at the moment).

Here's an example of my LINESTRING statement (stored in a string strGeo):

```
    LINESTRING(41.942587758675 -85.636084221926,41.9425261573997 -85.6360833224383,41.9423450573927 -85.6360807217602,41.9423035553449 -85.6360801225198,41.9421639573891 -85.6360781210972,41.9421098574371 -85.6360773225739,41.9420307561342 -85.6360762213003)
```

I then perform this operation on that string (VB.NET)

```
    Dim strSql As New SqlChars(New SqlString(strGeo))
    Dim geo As SqlGeography = SqlGeography.STLineFromText(strSql, 4326)
```

I've added appropriate references to Microsoft.SqlServer.Types from the SQL Server 2012 Feature pack, but when my debugger hits the SqlGeography line, I get this:

```
    System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.GeodeticIsValid(GeoMarshalData g, Double eccentricity, Boolean forceKatmai, Boolean& result, Boolean& isSmallerThanAHemisphere)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.GeodeticIsValid(GeoData& g, Double eccentricity, Boolean forceKatmai)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.IsValidExpensive(Boolean forceKatmai)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography..ctor(GeoData g, Int32 srid)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STLineFromText(SqlChars lineStringTaggedText, Int32 srid)
    at ShpFileProcessor.Module1.ProcessFile(FileInfo fil) in C:\Users\Chet Cromer\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\NorthernLights\ShpFileProcessor\ShpFileProcessor\Module1.vb:line 180
```

I cannot find SqlServerSpatial110.dll anywhere on my computer. I have SQL Express 2012 installed, and can find SqlerverSpatial.dll in both SYSTEM32 and SYSWOW64, but VS will not let me register either of those files.

I've noticed that if I use TWO parentheses in my LINESTRING like this I get a different error:

```
    LINESTRING((41.942587758675 -85.636084221926,41.9425261573997 -85.6360833224383,41.9423450573927 -85.6360807217602,41.9423035553449 -85.6360801225198,41.9421639573891 -85.6360781210972,41.9421098574371 -85.6360773225739,41.9420307561342 -85.6360762213003))

    System.FormatException: 24141: A number is expected at position 27 of the input. The input has (41.942587758675.
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.RecognizeDouble()
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseLineStringText()
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ParseText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STLineFromText(SqlChars lineStringTaggedText, Int32 srid)
    at ShpFileProcessor.Module1.ProcessFile(FileInfo fil) in C:\Users\Chet Cromer\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\NorthernLights\ShpFileProcessor\ShpFileProcessor\Module1.vb:line 180
```

(Before you count characters, position 27 is the space between the first lat/lon combo)

I expect that my first string format is the correct format, but at this point I'm not sure, and I'm not sure what to do with the SqlServerSpatial110.dll issue.

Anybody been down this road? Am I missing something?

Comment: I've also tried, to make sure my line is not too complex, using a string like this:

LINESTRING(0 0,1 1)

And I get the same results.

Comment: hi , i preffer you read MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee642119(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The second error I know about:

LINESTRING((41.942587758675

Two open parenthesis. The only time I got this error (the "a number is expected" thing) was when I randomly from copy/pasting had two open parenthesis.

Regarding the error you got on libraries, the SQL Server Spatial DLL is unmanaged code. You can find more info here, but make sure you have the right version (32/64) on your project and select the "copy to output direct = always" option.

http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/spatial-applications-in-windows-azure-redux-including-denali/